# Is it really a array sorting bug of chrome and ie?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting

I create a very simple array sorting script, it works on Firefox, but chrome and ie are giving me an unordered array.

```
var arr = ["2017-02-17",
"2017-02-17",
"2017-02-16",
"2017-02-15",
"2017-02-16",
"2017-02-15",
"2017-02-14",
"2017-02-16",
"2017-02-17",
"2017-02-17",
"2017-02-13"];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {return a>b;});
console.log(arr);
```

Is is a chrome/ie bug or I missed something? I hardly believe that chrome and ie have differenrt js engine have the same issue.

Comment: simply calling arr.sort()  will do

Comment: Forgot the data format, try var arr = ["17", 
"17", 
"16", 
"15", 
"16", 
"15", 
"14", 
"16", 
"17", 
"17", 
"13"];
It also return me unordered list.

Answer (score 2):

You might use the right comparison for [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and use it as return value, instead of a single `true`/`false`, which does eliminate the negative value, which is needed.

While you have [ISO 6801](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date strings, you could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for it.

```js
var arr = ["2017-02-17", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-13"];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
console.log(arr);
```

And if you do not care about *Unicode code points*, you could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

without *compareFunction*

```js
var arr = ["2017-02-17", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-13"];

arr.sort();
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: it looks like well formed ISO date to me,

Comment: Just note that Unicode code points does not really apply here as all chars in the date strings shown are within the ASCII range (assuming a normal "dash"/- is always used) so a sort() should be pretty stable here.

Comment: @K3N, right, in this case. I thought, i should mention the difference between sort without callback and localeCompare.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have dates as string, its always better to create a date and check equality.

Comparing string can have issues as you can have date from any format. Classic example would be `yyyy-m-d`.

In string comparison, `2017-1-12` is greater than `2017-08-17`.

```js
var arr = ["2017-02-17", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-7", "2017-02-13"];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var d1 = new Date(a);
  var d2 = new Date(b);
  return +d1 - +d2;
})

console.log(arr)
```

---

**Note:** As pointed out by [@K3N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/k3n), if input will always be in ISO format, then you can use any way for string comparison (example [@Nina Scholz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42339008/3783478)).  But if there is a possibility of receiving input in any other format, I'd suggest comparing Date Objects instead.

Comment: They appear to be in ISO format and should sort just fine as strings (default for Array.sort()). The problem lies in the return value which should be -1/0/1 and not a boolean.

Comment: True, if that's the case, but if in ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd) the date would be 2017-01-12 and not cause any problem.

Comment: @K3N Updated my answer  with caveat and credited you. I'd still keep my approach as this would help people with inconsistent format. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use simply sort without passing a `callback` function.

```
arr.sort();
```

```js
var arr = ["2017-02-17",
"2017-02-17",
"2017-02-16",
"2017-02-15",
"2017-02-16",
"2017-02-15",
"2017-02-14",
"2017-02-16",
"2017-02-17",
"2017-02-17",
"2017-02-13"];
arr.sort();
console.log(arr);
```